# how to handle absolute url to css with grunt-usemin

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I am using grunt-usemin to build an app project

css are linked with absolute paths:

```
  <!-- build:css(.) /app/css/libs.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app-dev/lib/css/style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app-dev/lib/css/another.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

javascript files are linked with relative paths:

```
  <!-- build:js js/app.js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

the grunt config:

```
  useminPrepare: {
        html: 'app-dev/index.html',
        options: {
              dest: 'app'
        }
  },
  usemin: {
        html: ['app/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['app/css/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
              assetsDirs: ['app']
        }
  }
```

The problem is there is one spare subfolder level in the css output:

```
app
- app
- - css
- - - libs.css
- js
- - app.js
- etc
```

while the reference in the outputed html file is correct

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/css/libs.css">
```

How to output the css to the correct folder hierarchy?

Comment: for now, I added two hacky tasks with contrib-copy to copy the files and contrib-clean to delete the old folder…

Comment: Does this remedy itself if you change `<!-- build:css(.) /app/css/libs.css -->` to `<!-- build:css(.) css/libs.css -->`? Otherwise I would look at changing your globbing pattern from {,*/}* to **/*

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the / in front of your build path

```
<!-- build:css app/css/libs.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app-dev/lib/css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app-dev/lib/css/another.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML file should be under "app" folder as well, so you can remove "/app-dev".